# mysqli_fetch_row how does it works with while loop?

Tags: php

Each time in a ***while()*** loop when ***mysqli_fetch_array($result)*** is called;
How does it come to know that it have to fetch another row from the database query result which we have saved in ***$result*** ?

And how it knows that all the rows from ***$result*** have been fetched?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$result` points to an object that maintains some internal state, a cursor. This cursor points to the row to fetch next. Each time you call `mysqli_fetch_array()` it gets the next result, and updates the cursor, until it gets to the last row, after which it returns false, and the `while()` terminates.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896634/mysqli-fetch-row-how-does-it-work?rq=1).

Comment: It's still unclear how does it work...?
 I mean the proper functionality.. the technique behind it

Comment: You could look at the code example here ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503216/mysql-fetch-array-while-loop-how-does-it-work ) under James Everest's answer - which has a nice self-contained example with a PHP class.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call ***mysqli_fetch_array*** it pulls the next row from your query. That while loop keeps returning true while the ***mysqli_fetch_array*** still has something left to assign to the variable $row. Once it's out of rows, it has nothing left to give the variable, and false is returned.

For more detail see this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503216/mysql-fetch-array-while-loop-how-does-it-work)